# Remove data attribute from all same elements besides current one

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have following statement

```
            if(play == '4'){
                $(this).removeAttr('data-playa');
                $(this).attr("data-pausea",'5');
            }
```

Basically it replaces `data-playa="4"` to `data-pausea="5"` of the current element. `$(this)` referees to current anchor tag with class of article-play so `$(article-play)` . I need to somehow edit this code to also apply following to all `$(article-play)` elements on a page, except current one:

```
                $(article-play).removeAttr('data-pausea');
                $(article-play).attr("data-playa",'4');
```

So it will logically be like this

```
        if(play == '4'){
            // Apply this to current .article-play
            $(this).removeAttr('data-playa');
            $(this).attr("data-pausea",'5');
        // Apply this to all other .article-play on a page
        $(article-play).removeAttr('data-pausea');
        $(article-play).attr("data-playa",'4');
        }
```

Comment: Use `removeData('pausea')` instead of `removeAttr()`. Also, use `data()` to set data for the selected elements.

Comment: @BradM whats the difference?

Comment: @llya I'm not sure of all the difference myself, but jQuery doesn't just interpret data as a standard element attribute; it holds references in memory. Simply removing the attribute may not actually remove the data from jQuery's memory.

Comment: @BradM Depends on how the data will be referenced later, and also the version of Jquery in play...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At its simplest:

```
$(this).removeAttr('data-playa').attr("data-pausea",'5');
$(article-play).not(this).removeAttr('data-pausea').attr("data-playa",'4');
```

If you were to use the `data()` method instead:

```
$(this).removeData('playa').data("pausea",'5');
$(article-play).not(this).removeData('pausea').data("playa",'4');
```

If the other elements are siblings, however:

```
$(this).removeData('playa').data("pausea",'5').siblings()
    .removeData('pausea').data("playa",'4');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(article-play).not(this).removeAttr('data-pausea');
```

?